# Group results of dataframe by several columns and count the different unique values per each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has this structure:

```
Group    Subgroup    Results1       Results2
  A         s1          OK             NOK
  A         s1          OK             OK
  A         s2          NOK            NOK
  A         s2          OK             NOK
  B         s3          OK             Not tested
  B         s3          Not tested     NOK
  B         s4          OK             NOK
```

And I want to get the count of each Results column in some kind like:

```
                            Results1                    Results2
                     OK    NOK    Not tested         OK    NOK    Not tested
    A       s1       2     1      0                  1     2      0
    A       s2       1     3      ...                ...   ...    ...
    B       s3       ...   ...    ...                ...   ...    ...
    B       s4       ...   ...    ...                ...   ...    ...
```

Is there any way to achieve this with Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns names:

```
df = df.melt(['Group','Subgroup'])

df = (pd.crosstab([df['Group'], df['Subgroup']], [df['variable'], df['value']])
        .rename_axis([None, None], axis=1))
print (df)
               Results1               Results2              
                    NOK Not tested OK      NOK Not tested OK
Group Subgroup                                              
A     s1              0          0  2        1          0  1
      s2              1          0  1        2          0  0
B     s3              0          1  1        1          1  0
      s4              0          0  1        1          0  0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for.

I did not know it could be performed so easily, although I will keep "playing" with the methods to fully understand what they do. Thanks.